# Error while using declare for type restriction in PHP7

Tags: php, return-type, declare

I am currently practicing PHP7 with small code. I was using this code to practice scalar type declaration:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function div(float $x, float $y)
{
    return $x / $y;
}

function sub(int $x, int $y)
{
    return $x - $y;
}

var_dump(div(2, 3.5)); // float(7)
var_dump(sub('2', 3)); // Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to sub() must be of the type integer, string given..
```

But when I run this code my server gives 500 error. But when I remove declare() it works. My server is running PHP7.

Comment: '2' is string .. and the error is pretty clear.. 
Strict type is validating the type which is : int - 2 and string - '2'

Comment: My server is not running this script and gives 500 server error

Comment: Its your server configuration.. check about display errors and how to enable them ..

Comment: How to enable them in PHP7?

Comment: Thanks I found the way :)

Comment: Just add ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at the beginning of your script to avoid the 500 server error and see the actual PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

Using declare(strict_types=1); you are telling php to don't use coercive type hints, so you're string will not be converted to an integer.
This is why you get TypeError.
If you remove declare(strict_types=1) php use coercive type hints so your string will be converted to an integer and php doesn't throw a TypeError.